# Is there a tool to convert geoRSS into geoJSON?

Tags: geospatial, tool-request, data-format, conversion

I have a geoRSS file that I would like to convert to geoJSON to use it with Leaflet. I found [MyGeodata Converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/) (mentioned on [What are the most useful formats in which to release geospatial data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/317/1344)), but it doesn't allow to use geoRSS as an input format.

Is there a tool out there that handles geoRSS to geoJSON conversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most versatile tool for geo format conversion is ogr2ogr in [gdal](http://www.gdal.org/). [Here's an online front end](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) that uses ogr2ogr to convert to and from GeoJSON, and it supports GeoRSS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ogr2ogr does this job efficiently. Install, GDAL/OGR then run below command.

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON target.geojson geoRSS.xml`

(here `target.geojson` is the geojson file to be generated, while `geoRSS.xml` is actual feed file. You need to download it before you run above command.)